# What's the significance of the polar bear having a Japanese name in Dolittle?

Tags: analysis, the-voyage-of-doctor-dolittle

In the 2020 movie *Dolittle* (a.k.a *The Voyage of Doctor Dolittle*) there's a polar bear that is called Yoshi (a Japanese name). What's the significance of this name for a polar bear? Does the bonnet that he wears have any relation?

Comment: Its a Chullo, right?  So South American / Generic Ski-ware.

Comment: I'm assuming they named him Yoshi to appeal to overseas audiences. They hired an all-star anime cast of voice actors to do the dubbing in Japan

Comment: I'm nervous about responding because it *could* become heated, which we should try to avoid.  However I genuinely can't find anything relating to controversy about "ideology" being responsible for an audience backlash for this movie, in any market.   The movie got panned by critics (because it seems to be a pretty terrible movie) and released just as the pandemic was taking hold.

Comment: The other animals have an eclectic range of names. Poly is short for Polynesia (noting that parrots are [often called Polly](https://www.mentalfloss.com/article/55350/why-do-we-call-parrots-polly)), Chee-Chee (a gorilla, but originally a **ch**impanz**ee**), Dab-Dab (an alliterative Duck), Jip (an onomatopoeic dog) and Tutu (an onomatopoeic owl). The other animals have mundane Western names; Kevin, Betsy and Barry. Plimpton and Yoshi seem the 'odd names out' as it's not very easy to see why the makers picked those.